# Selenium IDE v.3.x と Selenium の連携は可能でしょうか？

Tags: python, selenium, テスト

UIテストを作成したく、方法を検討しています。

対象URIが大量にあるので、まず Selenium IDE で大枠を作成して、作成したテストをExportしてSeleniumで扱うと良いかと考えました。

- Firefox : 68.0.1
- Selenium IDE : Version 3.12.0

次のようなポストなど参考にしたのですが、上記環境では、作成したテストをExportボタンは存在せず。

- [selenium IDEで作ったテストケースのエクスポート](https://qiita.com/takky/items/9a2c1dc36c1a729c56cb#selenium-ide%E3%81%A7%E4%BD%9C%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88)

  > Selenium IDE バージョン : 2.8.0と表示されてる

別途確認したところ、Selenium IDE で保存したテスト自体は *.side という拡張子で、内容はJSONのように見受けられました。

- aaa.side by Selenium IDE v3.12.0

```
{
  "id": "b22dd3a5-3355-44a0-8236-d8e17228aab6",
  "version": "2.0",
  "name": "aaa",
  "url": "https://www.google.com",
  "tests": [{
    "id": "0410fbef-53eb-4d01-8ad7-3bcab4ecee8c",
    "name": "test-google",
    "commands": [{
      "id": "caa38ded-28cc-4d8d-91ff-80509459dcb3",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "open",
      "target": "/",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
...以下省略
```

Selenium IDE v3ですと、Exportする方法ではなく .side ファイルを直接扱う方法があるのでしょうか？

なお、Seleniumは Python か JS で扱いたいと思っています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

右クリックメニューに「Export」というメニューがあり、そこからエクスポートできます。

[image: Export]

Comment: あ、、、見逃してました。Tests名で右クリックしたメニューで上記、確認しました。ありがとうございます！！